# Dynamic destination in Spring Cloud Stream from Azure Event Hub to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Stream to process messages sent to an Azure Event Hub instance. Those messages should be routed to a tenant-specific topic determined at runtime, based on message content, on a Kafka cluster. For development purposes, I'm running Kafka locally via Docker.
I've done some research about bindings not known at configuration time and have found that dynamic destination resolution might be exactly what I need for this scenario.

However, the only way to get my solution working is to use `StreamBridge`. I would rather use the dynamic destination header `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination`, in that way the processor could be written as a `Function<>` instead of a `Consumer<>` (it is not properly a sink). The main concern about this approach is that, since the final solution will be deployed with Spring Data Flow, I'm afraid I will have troubles configuring the streams if using StreamBridge.

Moving on to the code, this is the processor function, I stripped away the unrelated parts

```java
    private static final String OUTPUT_DESTINATION_TEMPLATE = "%s.gateway-report";
    private static final String STREAM_DESTINATION_HEADER = "spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination";
    private static final String TENANT_ID_HEADER = "tenant-id";

    @Bean
    public Function<Message<String>, Message<String>>
    routeMessageToTenantDestination(TenantGatewayDeviceService gatewayDeviceService) {
        return msg -> {
            final String tenantId = "test";
            final String destination = String.format(OUTPUT_DESTINATION_TEMPLATE, tenantId);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg.getPayload())
                    .setHeader(STREAM_DESTINATION_HEADER, destination)
                    .setHeader(TENANT_ID_HEADER, tenantId)
                    .build();
        };
    }
```

and this is my application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        routeMessageToTenantDestination-in-0:
          binder: kafka-evthub
          destination: gateway-report
          group: report-processor
      dynamic-destinations:
      binders:
        kafka-ioc:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              brokers: localhost:29092
        kafka-evthub:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              brokers: xxxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net:9093
              configuration:
                sasl:
                  jaas:
                    config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=*******;SharedAccessKey=********";
                  mechanism: PLAIN
                security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      default-binder: kafka-ioc
```

My relevant dependencies in pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is the exception I get each time the function fires

```
2022-01-20 10:56:18.848 ERROR 2258917 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [... stripped away ...]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:385)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:416)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2588)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2569)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2483)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2405)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2284)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1958)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1353)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1236)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.resolveDestination(StreamBridge.java:276)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.doSendMessage(FunctionConfiguration.java:604)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:597)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 32 more
```

I've tried different things, f.i. manually creating the destination topic, configuring an explicit destination binding with the same name assigned to the header (not a definitive solution, just for testing), but I keep getting this exception. I've also tried to provide a `NewDestinationBindingCallback<>` and I can see from printing a log that the framework enters the method, but nevertheless I keep getting the same error.

This happens also with the other approach for integrating Spring Cloud Stream with Event Hubs, namely the library `azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs`.

As I said previously, I've found a workaround in relying to StreamBridge, but this solution seems less desirable to me and I would like to understand what I'm missing.

EDIT: I made a small step forward and managed to make it work by downgrading spring boot starter version from `2.6.2` to `2.4.4`

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

and setting

```xml
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

instead of `2021.0.0` in pom.xml, as found in the sample provided by sobychacko. However, it seems like a regression, or something is missing in my configuration to make this work with the most recent version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is causing the issues you have. I just created a basic [sample app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-sendto-dest-header) demonstrating the `sendto.destination` header and verified that the app works as expected. It is a multi-binder application with two Kafka clusters connected. The function will consume from the first cluster and then using the `sendto` header, produce the output to the second cluster. Compare the code/config in this sample with your app and see what is missing.

I see references to `StreamBridge` in the stacktrace you shared. However, when using the `sendto.destination` header, it shouldn't go through `StreamBridge`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to experiment with your sample to see what I'm missing. Just one clarification from running your sample: is it correct that data are written also in topic "dataOut" on the first cluster, which should be the "source"? I would expect the first cluster to only have dataIn topic and the dataOut topic to be in the second cluster.

Comment: `dataIn` is on cluster-1 and `dataOut` is on cluster-2.

Comment: I asked because while running docker-compose and the jar from the sample as it is, without changing anything, issuing the command "kafkacat -b localhost:port -L" I can see that on kafka1 (port 9092) the listed topics are dataIn, dataOut and process-out-0. On the second cluster kafka2 (port 9093) only the topic dataOut is present. Uppercase data is present in dataOut topic of both cluster (checked by listening on topics with kafkacat). I was just wondering why the dataOut topic seems to be created (and written to) also on cluster kafka1, the example is working perfectly fine :)

Comment: It seems that changing spring boot version to 2.6.2 and spring cloud version to 2021.0.0 breaks the sample code in the exact same way of my program. See my edit for details. Is something changed and the configuration has to be adapted in some ways, or is it a bug/regression? I used spring initializr with the most recent version for the framework and I checked against the latest version of the docs.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a regression issue. I will check on that and get back here.

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce the error? Should I open an issue in the spring-cloud-stream repository?